# Apply superposition principle to compute current in the 2 Ω resistor

Tags: circuit-analysis, resistors, current-measurement, superposition

So in this question what I tried to do was first remove the 6A source and then try to apply the current divider rule according to which the current **I = 24 x (4/12) = 8A** and then remove the 24A source and then again try to apply the current divider rule according to which the current **i = 6 x (6/12) = 3A** and the final answer I arrived at was **I(total) = I-i(cause 3A is in opposite direction) = 5A**. Is it the correct way to apply the current divider rule in this question?

Ignore the blue dash in the question.

[image]

*Fig. 2.120.*

All resistors are in ohms.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, that appears to be the right technique. You removed (open circuited the current sources) and correctly split the remaining driving current by the correct ratio. In other words, when removing the 6 amp source you are left with 24 amps flowing into a 4 Ω resistor that is in parallel with 2 Ω in series with 6 Ω. One-third of the current (24 amps) will therefore flow from left to right through the 2 Ω resistor.

Similar story for when the 24 amp source is removed. Good work.